# Monitor - Not Optimum Mode, recommended Mode 1440x900 60 Hz

Tags: display

Samsung monitor of desktop computer is not able to display and shows `Not optimal mode error` `Recommended Mode 1440x900 60 Hz` while I connect it to desktop but it works when i check it from my laptop (extended window). So my question is How to solve this problem. I had gone to certain website in search of the solution (like [here](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080122051602AAt4Fpp))but couldn't succeed in solving it. I expect solution from experience user. It work when I open in safe mode and When I reduce the resolution and restart window in normal mode I again loop in above error.

Configuration:-
Operating System :- Window 8 x86 bits

Comment: Your question is very unclear as written. I assume when you say CPU you mean a desktop computer. Is the issue that laptop display the correct resolution and your desktop won't?

Comment: @BradPatton I had updated my question...

Comment: Both the laptop and the desktop are running Windows 8? If the desktop is not displaying the optimum resolution, then what resolution is it displaying?

Comment: Thank you. So what resolution is the monitor at when you receive the error message? Or is the screen just black? (60 Hz is not a resolution, it refers to the refresh rate)

Comment: @dtmland When I reduce the resolution and restart, error message animated in black screen.

Comment: What is the _exact_ model number of your Samsung monitor? (You can usually find it on a sticker on the back.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this may not be good solution but If I Were you, I would tried to re-install the operating system. (Which may adjust the environment for screen resolution and refresh rate during installation)